# Return the days of the week concatenated when provided a string of consecutive days of the week

Tags: javascript, function, helper

I need of a function that can take a string of days like "Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri" and return "Mon-Fri" Of course, it cannot simply return first and last concatenated with "-" but should account for "Mon,Tues,Thurs,Fri" in that case could either return the input string OR "Mon-Tues, Thurs-Fri"

Virtual cheers to whoever can help out!

```js
function daysConcat(days) {
  let key = ['Sun','Mon','Tues','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
  let daysArr = days.split(',');
  let consecutive = true;
  let lastIndex = '';

  let concatDays = daysArr.filter((day, i, arr) => {
    if (day === arr[arr.length-1] && consecutive && key.indexOf(day) === lastIndex+1) {
      return day;
    } else if (day === arr[0]) {
      lastIndex = key.indexOf(day);
      return day;
    } else if (key.indexOf(day) === lastIndex+1) {
        lastIndex = key.indexOf(day);
    } else {
      consecutive = false;
    }
  })

  if (concatDays.length > 1) {
    return `${concatDays[0]} - ${concatDays[concatDays.length-1]}`
  } else {
    return days
  }

}

let consecutiveA = 'Mon,Tues,Wed,Thu,Fri';
console.log(daysConcat(consecutiveA));

let consecutiveB = 'Mon,Tues,Wed,Thu';
console.log(daysConcat(consecutiveB));

let notConsecutiveA = 'Mon,Tues,Thu,Fri';
console.log(daysConcat(notConsecutiveA));

let notConsecutiveB = 'Sun,Mon,Tues,Thu,Fri';
console.log(daysConcat(notConsecutiveB));
```

Currently the above works according to my first "ask", though I would love a more elegant/straightforward approach. Also it will of course not produce "Mon-Tues, Thurs-Fri" for input string "Mon,Tues,Thurs,Fri" - any thoughts or improvements appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please don't use an external source to share you code, copy paste it directly in your question. There is a javascript snippet available here so we can test your code.

Comment: Also can you please give more details about the expected behavior with more examples.

Comment: What if it wraps around one or more times? e.g.: `Sun,Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri,Sat,Sun,Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri`

Comment: What if it contains crap, like `Mon,Dog,Wed`? I think your function should get an array `Date` or at least a string like `YYYY-MM-DD`, not just opinionated day of week.

Comment: @RoboRobok This works for my purpose but those are both great points to work towards as improvements.

Comment: Can you answer Wyck's question?

Comment: I’m not doing this for some kind of coding challenge guys. I can rely on the fact that the raw input is always an array of seven values starting with Sunday. In fact it comes from the database as an array [‘N’, ‘Y’, ‘Y’, ‘Y’, ‘Y’, ‘N’, ‘N’] Then according to locale I convert that to a string of active days and THEN feed to the above function along with a ”key” for days of the week. No crazy edge cases I’m aware of.

Comment: But again, I appreciate any feedback. You’re all welcome to brainstorm and suggest any improvement or code corrections to protect against such edge cases as you would.